# Por qué obtengo este error unfinished string near ´"

Tags: lua

No comprendo por qué obtengo el error que menciono en el titulo (unfinished string near ´").

He estado buscando pero no encuentro alguna información que me pueda ayudar si alguno fuera amable y revisara el code para ver que puede ser.

```
quest test begin
state start begin
    when letter with pc.is_gm() begin
        send_letter (" GM: test")
    end

    when button or info begin

        local query = [[
        SELECT player.player.name as m_name, player.player.level as m_level, player.player.exp as m_exp
        FROM player.player, account.account
        WHERE
            player.player.name not like '[%]%' AND
            date_sub(now(), interval 1 day) < player.player.last_play AND
            player.player.account_id=account.account.id AND
            account.account.status='OK'
        ORDER BY player.player.level DESC, player.player.exp DESC, player.player.name ASC
        LIMIT 10;
        ]]

        local res1, res2 = mysql_direct_query(query)
        say_title("Top "..res1.." players")
        for num1, str1 in ipairs(res2) do
            say_reward(num1.."\t"..str1.m_name.."\t"..str1.m_level.."\t"..str1.m_exp)
    end
end
```

end

Comment: Podrías aportar la versión de lua que utilizas y más detalles del error. ¿Te dice en qué liena se produce? Es muy problable que tenga que ver con los strings largos de lua "[[" pero si no das más información....

Comment: Y por cierto... ese código no tiene mucho sentido, al principio me parecía lua... pero...

Comment: utliza long string [=[string largo]==]=]  para que no te salte ese error!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré este [enlace](https://www.elitepvpers.com/forum/metin2-pserver-guides-strategies/3327940-release-mysql_direct_query-get_table_postfix-mysql_escape_string-written-c-lua.html) donde muestra la función `mysql_direct_query` que empleas en el código de arriba. Sí observas en dicho enlace **la entrada para dicha función es del tipo texto**.

Entonces para tratar de escarpar al formato de sql que estás usando puedes emplear un pequeño código que tome del siguiente [enlace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28795538/lua-sql-escape-string-try-unfinished-string-near)

```
function escape_sqli(source)
   local replacements = { ['"'] = '\\"', ["'"] = "\\'" }
   return source:gsub( "['\"]", replacements ) 
end
```

y luego actualizar la variable `query`

```
query = escape_sqli(query)
```

Habría que ver además la estructura de los outputs `res1, res2` ya que los empleas para concadenar texto, esto también podría ser la otra razón que causa el bug.